# Does the equals symbol always mean equality of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Assuming a set-theory based universe, is it right to be suspicious of the equality symbol, as it is used in say college textbooks?

For example, when we say 3 + 3 = 6, does it mean the set "3 + 3" is set-equal to the set "6", or is it merely a shorthand for "both sides have the same cardinality"?  Even if these two sets are set-equal, perhaps there are other examples where we write = but the underlying meaning is in fact an equivalence relation.

Comment: What do you mean by "the set 3+3" ?

Comment: When you encode a theory using set theory, many questions that have no actual significance in the theory being encoded become answered. This is one of those kinds of questions.

Comment: Yes, both sets are equal, under either the usual definition of addition of ordinals or the usual definition of addition of cardinals.

Comment: If you do not assume every object is a set, you can still define equality between arbitrary objects with the axioms: (1) x=x for all x,  (2) if x=y then can substitute the expression y for some or all expressions x in any statement S provided x is a free variable in S and y is not a bound variable in S. The other properties of equality, namely symmetry and transitivity, can be derived from these two axioms.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, we knew each other in college (we both TA'd the same class). As you can see from my humble question, I did not go into maths as a career. Hope you are well.

Comment: @Joseph I am, thank you. Small world. Remind me which class that was, if you remember.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, It was at Cal, Math54, probably Professor Ogus. I was the undergrad TA, the rest of you were grad students. It was a good group :-)

Comment: @Joseph Ah, yes! Ogus's approach to the material was very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notation is often overloaded for various purposes.

In set theoretic foundations, the natural number $0$ is usually defined to be the empty set, but the symbol $0$ is also used to express 'zero' as an integer, as a rational number, as a real number, and so on.

For example $0$-as-an-integer is really equal to the set $\{ (n,n) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, which is definitely not equal-as-a-set to $0$-as-a-natural-number. Does this mean that the proposition $0=0$ is false? Really its truth or falsity depends on whether both $0$ symbols refer to the same notion of 'zero': if one of them is $0$-as-a-natural number and the other is $0$-as-an-integer then it's false, since $\varnothing \ne \{ (n,n) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. At the same time, it's ridiculous to say that $0=0$ is false, since if you write it down you're *obviously* referring to the same zero! It's all dependent on context.

So returning to your question: the symbol $+$ is also overloaded. Presumably in this case it is understood to mean addition of natural numbers, in which case $m+n$ is the $n$th iterated successor of $m$; that is $m+n = m^{++\cdots+}$, where given a set $x$ we define $x^+ = x \cup \{ x \}$ and there are $n$ '$+$' symbols in the superscript; in this case, $3+3=6$ really does mean equality of sets, but $+$ is understood to mean addition of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Often times, the symbol is used to refer to other notions of equality as a function of the kind of work that is being done. In topology, $A=B$ often means that $A$ is homeomorphic, or possibly homotopy equivalent, to $B$, depending on context. Similarly, the symbol also sometimes refers to algebraic isomorphism, or analytic asymptotic equivalence.

In general, $=$ could be used to represent any equivalence relation in which the context is reasonably unambiguous or canonical. If, in stead one is examining a more ad-hoc equivalence, it is more likely that one will use the $\sim$ symbol. Of course, this is no more than a matter of preference and convention, and is largely irrelevant so long as the intent is well communicated.